# IceCast on Windows server 2008R2

Tags: windows, connect, hostname, icecast

I cannot get any source clients to connect to an instance of IceCast on a Windows Server 2008R2. I've spent weeks looking for anything that might help, but there really isn't much in the way of reading when it comes IceCast on Windows and where the source is on a different machine than the server.

Right now, this is the entire config file:

```
    <! This config file contains a minimal set of configurable parameters,
    and mostly just contains the things you need to change. We created
    this for those who got scared away from the rather large and heavily
    commented icecast.xml.dist file. -->
    <icecast>
        <limits>
            <sources>2</sources>
        </limits>
        <authentication>
            <source-password>secured</source-password>
            <relay-password>secured</relay-password>
            <admin-user>secured</admin-user>
            <admin-password>secured</admin-password>
        </authentication>

        <hostname>RadioStation-stream.school.edu</hostname>
        <listen-socket>
            <port>8000</port>
        </listen-socket>
        <fileserve>1</fileserve>
        <mount>
            <mount-name>/stream.ogg</mount-name>
            <max-listeners>100</max-listeners>
        </mount>
        <paths>
            <logdir>c:\users\filepath\logs</logdir>
            <webroot>c:\users\filepath\web</webroot>
            <adminroot>c:\users\filepath\admin</adminroot>
            <alias source="/" dest="/status.xsl"/>
        </paths>
        <logging>
            <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
            <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
            <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
        </logging>
    </icecast>
```

I may have typoed a thing or two in copying it over (since I had to do it all by hand - the config file is on the server and I'm on the station computer right now).

The server is owned by the school, and as far as I'm aware, is on stored off-site, but is still on the local domain through a WAN connection. I can only connect to the server using remote desktop and either my personal domain account or the radio station's domain account for the school computers.
I suspect the issue is with *hostname*, but I cannot be sure. IceCast is being hosted on the same server that we are hosting our website on (that will eventually listen in on the stream as well). I've tried using the domain for our website (website.school.edu), as well as just the IP address for the server. The "RadioStation-stream.school.edu" is my latest attempt, but no success.

I've tried using Butt and Sam Broadcaster, and neither one can connect.

I know the server works, when I switch *hostname* back to "localhost", and type "http://localhost:8000" into internet explorer inside the server, it loads up the IceCast server page, and I can login with the admin credentials I've created. If I extend the address out to "http://localhost:8000/stream.ogg" Internet explorer cannot find the page. If I try to connect to "http://server-ip:8000" from an external client, the web browser times out - same deal if I extend the address to include the stream.

I've tried installing IceCast to the program file(x86) folder, as well as to the webroot folder (where a website could potentially be hosted, but none currently are - our site is in a different webroot folder, on a different drive on the server).
I've spent the last two nights trying to get sources to connect to the server, and I feel like I've tried everything. I hope someone else sees something I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly your firewall configuration.

If you open up TCP ports 8000 and 8001, I suspect that things will work just fine for you.

Comment: I *think* this is what fixed - but to be honest, I cannot be sure. The TCP ports were open on our server, and the tech department told us they were open in their Firewall - but it did not start working until about 12 hours later, when I decided to try connecting on a whim and everything worked.
Now we're dealing with a couple other issues (stream not working off-campus, tries to download a file instead of play in IE, nothing related to this issue.

Comment: @brownem, If the browser is downloading the stream, then you're linking to the stream rather than the playlist file.  If you link to the playlist file, it will open up in the media player.

Comment: there is no playlist file. It is a live stream of music, and just because of the way the studio needed to be set up, music is passed through our external mixer, mixed with the Mics and external CD stacks, then passed back into the computer before being sent out to IceCast.
I am pretty sure it doesn't play nice with IE is because we're using HTML5 for the audio stream at the moment. I haven't had time to work in the flash fallback just yet (Finals and such).

Comment: Yes, my point is that if you want the stream to play externally (in an audio player outside of the browser), then you need to link to a playlist file.  Just make a file with one line being the URL of your stream, save it as `.m3u`, and assuming your server is configured to server the file correctly, it will work just fine.